# Extending windows named pipe to handle clients information

Tags: c, windows, driver, named-pipes

Handling & processing data from named pipes.

I am trying to implement a service provider to connect with a hardware device. 
request some pointers on my approach to implement a robust system.

Mentioned are the raised requirements

1. Receive data from other EXE process
2. To process received Q information and send response information in clients response channel.
3. Asynchronously send information on some failure to client response channel.

TO implement the mentioned system:

1. Selected 2 named pipe (ClntcommandRecv & ClntRespSend) .bcz of between process (IPC)
2. ClntcommandRecv pipe will be used as "Named Pipe Server Using Overlapped" I/O"
3. ClntRespSend pipe will be used for sending the processed information.
4. ClntRespSend will also need to send all the async messages from service provider to connected application.

From here my implementation is straight forward.

Using  "Named Pipe Server Using Overlapped I/O" by documentation I will be able to address multiple client connection request and its data processing using single thread.
On init system will create a thread to hold connection instance of clients ClntRespSend pipe.

1. Since, it requires for device to tell its failures to connected clients asynchronously. 
   Is it advisable for system to have timeout operation on "WaitForMultipleObjects" or
   can we have readfile timeout counts after n timeout can we check for health info.WHich is advised
2. But, stuck in finding the best way to sync my ClntRespSend & ClntcommandRecv (MAPPIN).
   Need to get process id of the connected process.Since the system is developed under MINGW - WIN32 - server will not be able to get the process id directly by using (GetNamedPipeClientProcessId).
   Need to form a  message structure on getting a client connection.

This is the code which i am trying to extend:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
//#include <strsafe.h>

//#include <glib.h>

#define CONNECTING_STATE 0
#define READING_STATE 1
#define WRITING_STATE 2
#define INSTANCES 4
#define PIPE_TIMEOUT 5000
#define BUFSIZE 4096

typedef struct
{
   OVERLAPPED oOverlap;
   HANDLE hPipeInst;
   TCHAR chRequest[BUFSIZE];
   DWORD cbRead;
   TCHAR chReply[BUFSIZE];
   DWORD cbToWrite;
   DWORD dwState;
   BOOL fPendingIO;
   int processId;
} PIPEINST, *LPPIPEINST;


typedef struct
{
char appName[256];
int processId;
}PIPEHANDSHAKE;



VOID DisconnectAndReconnect(DWORD);
BOOL ConnectToNewClient(HANDLE, LPOVERLAPPED);
VOID GetAnswerToRequest(LPPIPEINST);

PIPEINST Pipe[INSTANCES];
HANDLE hEvents[INSTANCES];

HANDLE responsePipeHandle[INSTANCES];


DWORD WINAPI InstanceThread(LPVOID);

HANDLE hPipeHandles[10];
PULONG  s;

LPTSTR lpszPipename = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe");
LPTSTR lpszResponsePipe = TEXT("\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe1");


//GHashTable* hash;

int responsePipeConnectionHandler(VOID)
{
   BOOL   fConnected = FALSE;
   DWORD  dwThreadId = 0;
   HANDLE hPipe = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, hThread = NULL;
   int cbBytesRead;
   INT threadCount=0;
   //hash = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
   char bufferSize[512];
   for (;;)
   {
      _tprintf( TEXT("\nPipe Server: Main thread awaiting client connection on %s\n"), lpszResponsePipe);
      hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
              lpszResponsePipe,             // pipe name
          PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,       // read/write access
          PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |       // message type pipe
          PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |   // message-read mode
          PIPE_WAIT,                // blocking mode
          PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES, // max. instances
          BUFSIZE,                  // output buffer size
          BUFSIZE,                  // input buffer size
          0,                        // client time-out
          NULL);                    // default security attribute

      if (hPipe == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
          _tprintf(TEXT("CreateNamedPipe failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError());
          return -1;
      }

      // Wait for the client to connect; if it succeeds,
      // the function returns a nonzero value. If the function
      // returns zero, GetLastError returns ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED.

      fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, NULL) ?
         TRUE : (GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED);

      if(fConnected){
          PIPEHANDSHAKE processData;
          fConnected = ReadFile(
             hPipe,        // handle to pipe
             bufferSize,    // buffer to receive data
             sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE), // size of buffer
             &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read
             NULL);        // not overlapped I/O
          memset(&processData,0,sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE));
          memcpy(&processData,&bufferSize,sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE));
          printf("APP Process id: %d , app name: %s",processData.processId,processData.appName);

      }

    /*  if (fConnected)
      {
         printf("Client connected, creating a processing thread.\n");

         // Create a thread for this client.
         hThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,              // no security attribute
            0,                 // default stack size
            InstanceThread,    // thread proc
            (LPVOID) hPipe,    // thread parameter
            0,                 // not suspended
            &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID

         if (hThread == NULL)
         {
            _tprintf(TEXT("CreateThread failed, GLE=%d.\n"), GetLastError());
            return -1;
         }
         else CloseHandle(hThread);
       }
      else
        // The client could not connect, so close the pipe.
         CloseHandle(hPipe);*/
   }

   return 0;
}

int _tmain(VOID)
{
   DWORD i, dwWait, cbRet, dwErr,hThread;
   BOOL fSuccess;
   int dwThreadId;

// The initial loop creates several instances of a named pipe
// along with an event object for each instance.  An
// overlapped ConnectNamedPipe operation is started for
// each instance.
   // Create response pipe thread
     hThread = CreateThread(
      NULL,              // no security attribute
      0,                 // default stack size
      responsePipeConnectionHandler,    // thread proc
      NULL,    // thread parameter
      0,                 // not suspended
      &dwThreadId);      // returns thread ID


   if (hThread == NULL)
   {
       printf("Response server creation failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
       return 0;
   }


   for (i = 0; i < INSTANCES; i++)
   {

   // Create an event object for this instance.

      hEvents[i] = CreateEvent(
         NULL,    // default security attribute
         TRUE,    // manual-reset event
         TRUE,    // initial state = signaled
         NULL);   // unnamed event object

      if (hEvents[i] == NULL)
      {
         printf("CreateEvent failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
         return 0;
      }

      Pipe[i].oOverlap.hEvent = hEvents[i];

      Pipe[i].hPipeInst = CreateNamedPipe(
         lpszPipename,            // pipe name
         PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX |     // read/write access
         FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,    // overlapped mode
         PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |      // message-type pipe
         PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |  // message-read mode
         PIPE_WAIT,               // blocking mode
         INSTANCES,               // number of instances
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),   // output buffer size
         BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),   // input buffer size
         PIPE_TIMEOUT,            // client time-out
         NULL);                   // default security attributes

      if (Pipe[i].hPipeInst == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      {
         printf("CreateNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
         return 0;
      }

   // Call the subroutine to connect to the new client

      Pipe[i].fPendingIO = ConnectToNewClient(
         Pipe[i].hPipeInst,
         &Pipe[i].oOverlap);

      Pipe[i].dwState = Pipe[i].fPendingIO ?
         CONNECTING_STATE : // still connecting
         READING_STATE;     // ready to read
   }

   while (1)
   {
      dwWait = WaitForMultipleObjects(
         INSTANCES,    // number of event objects
         hEvents,      // array of event objects
         FALSE,        // does not wait for all
         INFINITE);    // waits indefinitely

   // dwWait shows which pipe completed the operation.

      i = dwWait - WAIT_OBJECT_0;  // determines which pipe
      if (i < 0 || i > (INSTANCES - 1))
      {
         printf("Index out of range.\n");
         return 0;
      }

   // Get the result if the operation was pending.

      if (Pipe[i].fPendingIO)
      {
         fSuccess = GetOverlappedResult(
            Pipe[i].hPipeInst, // handle to pipe
            &Pipe[i].oOverlap, // OVERLAPPED structure
            &cbRet,            // bytes transferred
            FALSE);            // do not wait

         switch (Pipe[i].dwState)
         {
         // Pending connect operation
            case CONNECTING_STATE:
               if (! fSuccess)
               {
                   printf("Error %d.\n", GetLastError());
                   return 0;
               }
               Pipe[i].dwState = READING_STATE;
               break;

         // Pending read operation
            case READING_STATE:
               if (! fSuccess || cbRet == 0)
               {
                  DisconnectAndReconnect(i);
                  continue;
               }
               Pipe[i].cbRead = cbRet;
               Pipe[i].dwState = WRITING_STATE;
               break;

         // Pending write operation
            case WRITING_STATE:
               if (! fSuccess || cbRet != Pipe[i].cbToWrite)
               {
                  DisconnectAndReconnect(i);
                  continue;
               }
               Pipe[i].dwState = READING_STATE;
               break;

            default:
            {
               printf("Invalid pipe state.\n");
               return 0;
            }
         }
      }

   // The pipe state determines which operation to do next.

      switch (Pipe[i].dwState)
      {
         case READING_STATE:
            fSuccess = ReadFile(
               Pipe[i].hPipeInst,
               Pipe[i].chRequest,
               BUFSIZE*sizeof(TCHAR),
               &Pipe[i].cbRead,
               &Pipe[i].oOverlap);
            if (fSuccess && Pipe[i].cbRead != 0)
            {
               Pipe[i].fPendingIO = FALSE;
               Pipe[i].dwState = WRITING_STATE;
               continue;
            }
            dwErr = GetLastError();
            if (! fSuccess && (dwErr == ERROR_IO_PENDING))
            {
               Pipe[i].fPendingIO = TRUE;
               continue;
            }
            DisconnectAndReconnect(i);
            break;
         case WRITING_STATE:
            GetAnswerToRequest(&Pipe[i]);
            fSuccess = WriteFile(
               Pipe[i].hPipeInst,
               Pipe[i].chReply,
               Pipe[i].cbToWrite,
               &cbRet,
               &Pipe[i].oOverlap);
            if (fSuccess && cbRet == Pipe[i].cbToWrite)
            {
               Pipe[i].fPendingIO = FALSE;
               Pipe[i].dwState = READING_STATE;
               continue;
            }
            dwErr = GetLastError();
            if (! fSuccess && (dwErr == ERROR_IO_PENDING))
            {
               Pipe[i].fPendingIO = TRUE;
               continue;
            }
            DisconnectAndReconnect(i);
            break;

         default:
         {
            printf("Invalid pipe state.\n");
            return 0;
         }
      }
  }

  return 0;
}

VOID DisconnectAndReconnect(DWORD i)
{
  if (! DisconnectNamedPipe(Pipe[i].hPipeInst) )
   {
      printf("DisconnectNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
   }

   Pipe[i].fPendingIO = ConnectToNewClient(
      Pipe[i].hPipeInst,
      &Pipe[i].oOverlap);

   Pipe[i].dwState = Pipe[i].fPendingIO ?
      CONNECTING_STATE : // still connecting
      READING_STATE;     // ready to read
}

BOOL ConnectToNewClient(HANDLE hPipe, LPOVERLAPPED lpo)
{
   BOOL fConnected, fPendingIO = FALSE;
   fConnected = ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, lpo);
   if (fConnected)
   {
      printf("ConnectNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
      return 0;
   }

   switch (GetLastError())
   {
   // The overlapped connection in progress.
      case ERROR_IO_PENDING:
         fPendingIO = TRUE;
         break;
      case ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED:
         if (SetEvent(lpo->hEvent))
            break;
      default:
      {
         printf("ConnectNamedPipe failed with %d.\n", GetLastError());
         return 0;
      }
   }

   return fPendingIO;
}


int rxProccesIdMsg(HANDLE pipe)
{
    PIPEHANDSHAKE pipeInfo;
    CHAR bufferSize[512] = {'\0'};
    INT cbBytesRead;
    BOOL fSuccess;
      PIPEHANDSHAKE processData;
      fSuccess = ReadFile(
              pipe,        // handle to pipe
       bufferSize,    // buffer to receive data
       sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE), // size of buffer
       &cbBytesRead, // number of bytes read
       NULL);        // not overlapped I/O
    memset(&processData,0,sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE));
    memcpy(&processData,&bufferSize,sizeof(PIPEHANDSHAKE));


    if ( (!fSuccess))
    {
        printf("Client: READ Server Pipe Failed(%d)\n",GetLastError());
        CloseHandle(pipe);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Client: READ Server Pipe Success(%d)\n",GetLastError());
        printf("APP Process id: %d , app name: %s",processData.processId,processData.appName);
        //Sleep(3*100);
    }
    return processData.processId;
}

VOID GetAnswerToRequest(LPPIPEINST pipe)
{
   _tprintf( TEXT("[%d] %s\n"), pipe->hPipeInst, pipe->chRequest);
  // StringCchCopy( pipe->chReply, BUFSIZE, TEXT("Default answer from server") );
   strncpy(pipe->chReply, "Default answer from server",BUFSIZE);
   pipe->cbToWrite = (lstrlen(pipe->chReply)+1)*sizeof(TCHAR);
}
```

Comment: While you question is a valid one, still SO does not encourage open-ended q's like `What is mechanism that is advised for this extension`.

Comment: What are you stuck on?  What specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @HarryJohnston : added information request your views

Comment: I'm not sure why you want the process ID for the client, but GetNamedPipeClientProcessId should work perfectly well.  There's no reason why using MinGW would mean you can't call this function.  (You might have to declare it yourself if it isn't in the headers.)